# Why isnt this huggingface inference endpoint looping through my local files in a folder

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, llama, huggingface-hub

The LLM is Llama2 7b, it does a loop but it makes up its own emails, its not reading or looping through the specific path i want, ive looked everywhere for an answer but canr seem to find one.

Could someone know how to fix it so it will loop through and read my local text files on my local machine

```
import os
import glob
from huggingface_hub import InferenceClient

folder_path = '
text_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.txt"))
print(f"Text files found: {text_files}")

endpoint_url = ""
hf_token = ""

def read_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        content = file.read()
         return content

client = InferenceClient(endpoint_url, token=hf_token)

gen_kwargs = dict(max_new_tokens=512, top_k=30, top_p=0.9, temperature=0.2, repetition_penalty=1.02, stop_sequences=["\nUser:", "</s>"])

fixed_prompt = """You are a cybersecurity phishing expert. In every future output can you tell me if the email is "phish" or "clean"? be binary."""

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt'))
print(f"Text files found: {file_list}")

for filename in file_list:
    # Open the file and read its contents
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        content = file.read()
    
    # Fill in the fixed prompt with the file content
    prompt = fixed_prompt + f"\n{content}"
    
    # Generate text based on the prompt
    stream = client.text_generation(prompt, stream=True, details=True, **gen_kwargs)
    
    # Print the generated text
    for r in stream:
        print(r.token.text, end='')

print("\n")
```

Tried to use the glob library but its not working, no silly answers like have you checked your path, please :)